# What's the file difference between rails 3.2.0 and 3.2.7? (re: upgrading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diff, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to upgrade from rails 3.2.0 to 3.2.7 and I am looking for a comprehensive listing of app-context file changes between the two.

Comment: Could someone with at least 1500 reputation points please create/add the tag `ruby-on-rails-3.2.7`? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a tag for `3.2.7`, just the one for `3.2`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "please create the tag, and then add it to this question".. (if that is still possible).

Comment: I'm not sure it warrants a separate tag. There aren't any other sub-specific tags. I'll leave that for someone more familiar with ROR to decide. :-)

Comment: 3.2.7 is just a patch release with bug fixes and anything critical that was backported from 4.0. The API for 3.2.0 is pretty much identical to any other 3.2 release, except for a few deprecation warnings. I don't think having a 3.2.7 tag makes much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an annotated recursive diff of a rails [3.2.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/20/rails-3-2-0-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store/) app and a rails [3.2.7](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/7/26/ann-rails-3-2-7-has-been-released/) app, excluding `Gemfile.lock` and `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`. To upgrade, make these changes and run `bundle update`.

By the way, here are the intermediary release announcements: [3.2.1](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/26/rails-3-2-1-has-been-released/), [3.2.2](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/1/ann-rails-3-2-2-has-been-released/), [3.2.3](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/), [3.2.4](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/5/31/ann-rails-3-2-4-has-been-released/), [3.2.5](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/5/31/ann-rails-3-2-5-has-been-released/), [3.2.6](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/6/12/ann-rails-3-2-6-has-been-released/).

**Gemfile**

```
diff --recursive rails-3.2.0/depot/Gemfile rails-3.2.7/depot/Gemfile
3c3
< gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
---
> gem 'rails', '3.2.7'
18c18
<   # gem 'therubyracer'
---
>   # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
31c31
< # Use unicorn as the web server
---
> # Use unicorn as the app server
38c38
< # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
---
> # gem 'debugger'
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css** -- add space (cosmetic)

```
diff --recursive rails-3.2.0/depot/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css rails-3.2.7/depot/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
13c13
< */
---
>  */
```

**config/application.rb** -- add config lines (read about `whitelist_attributes` [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/))

```
diff --recursive rails-3.2.0/depot/config/application.rb rails-3.2.7/depot/config/application.rb
41a42,44
>     # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
>     config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
>
51c54
<     # config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
---
>     config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

**config/environments/production.rb** -- change comment

```
diff --recursive rails-3.2.0/depot/config/environments/production.rb rails-3.2.7/depot/config/environments/production.rb
23c23
<   # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
---
>   # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an exact file difference, you can use Github to compare the tags:

https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v3.2.0...v3.2.7#files_bucket

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for *app-context* file changes - for the purpose of upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.com/pkgdiff/) tool to create visual diffs for rails packages. To create the one for [3.2.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/tarball/v3.2.0) and [3.2.7](https://github.com/rails/rails/tarball/v3.2.7) run:

```
$ pkgdiff -old rails-3.2.0-0-gf36dcaf.tar.gz -new rails-3.2.7-0-gd1b9cf2.tar.gz
```

The output is [this HTML report](http://upstream-tracker.org/pkgdiff_reports/rails/3.2.0-0-gf36dcaf_to_3.2.7-0-gd1b9cf2/changes_report.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for *app-context file changes* - for the purpose of upgrading my app.